# PHP - determinar valores em euros e creditos

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho um site de vendas onde utilizo créditos para "descontos".

O que pretendo fazer é se o produto for 5.00€ e se o utilizador tiver 100 créditos

Esses 100 créditos irão descontar X valor aos 5.00€.

Exemplo, Sabendo que 10 créditos descontam cerca de 0.01 cêntimos (isto é uma ideia)

Como faço para que o código verifique os créditos e desconte no valor total?

Variáveis:

```
$cada10vale = 0.01;
$creditos_do_utilizador = $row['creditos'];
$preço_total_em_euros = $_SESSION['cart_total'];
```

Comment: ... `$preco_total_com_desconto = $preço_total_em_euros - (abs($creditos_do_utilizador / 10) * $cada10vale)`, não? Ou perdi algo na descrição do problema?

Comment: Vai descontar do valor total ou de um produto especifico?

Comment: conta do valor total apenas

Comment: $otal = $preço_total_em_euros - (abs($creditos_do_utilizador / 1000));

Comment: Cara, não use caracteres especiais nas variaveis, tira esse cedilha de preço porque vai dar pau cedo pu tarde.